# How to add column in datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, wpftoolkit

How i can add column in wpf toolkit datagrid from code behind?
this does not works:

```
DataGridTemplateColumn txtc = new DataGridTemplateColumn();
        txtc.Header = "2";
        myGrid.Columns.Add(txtc);
```

this is my grid :

```
 <Controls:DataGrid.CellStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Controls:DataGridCell}">
                <Setter Property="Background">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource myHighlighterConverter}">
                            <MultiBinding.Bindings>
                                <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"></Binding>
                                <Binding Path="Row"></Binding>
                            </MultiBinding.Bindings>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </Controls:DataGrid.CellStyle>
    </Controls:DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WPF 4 has its own DataGrid, the column you created is from that namespace, it is not compatible with the Toolkit-DataGrid. If you use WPF 4 you probably should not use the Toolkit DataGrid at all.

Comment: i know but it does not adds columns even vs gives such error : Error 2 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Windows.Controls.DataGridTemplateColumn' to 'Microsoft.Windows.Controls.DataGridColumn

Comment: @Acid: Why don't you add the error to the bloody question then?